# While installing mongodb in kali linux, I get errors in apt-get

Tags: mongodb, dependencies, kali-linux, aptitude

need help.
Trying to install Mongodb in kali linux 2, using the command

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org
```

but it always gives me the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-shell but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-tools but it is not going to be installed
```

I have tried installing those packages by themself, but couldn't be found in the repository of kali.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tz1bF.png

Comment: Have you `apt-get update`d?

Comment: Yes have tried.

Answer (score 3):

try Aptitude instead

```
sudo aptitude install mongodb-org
```

also did you try

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
```